# Regret in the linear regression setting

Tags: regression

I've seen the concept of regret apply mostly to online learning problems, but while going through the definition it does seem that is not bounded to this setting.

I'm trying to come with a simple example to explain this concept in terms of simple linear models.

The Wikipedia page does try to do it, but is incomplete at best, does anyone has a reference where there is a worked example of regret being applied in a linear regressions setting.

Comment: If we consider a linear regression to be a neural network with no hidden layer, an identity activation function on the output neuron, and mean squared error as the loss function, isn’t it exactly the same as any other online learning?

Answer (score 2):

A linear regression is a simple neural network that has no hidden layer and a linear (identity, really) activation function on the output neuron. Consequently, if you understand regret for a neural network (which it sounds like you do), you understand regret for a linear regression.